# SQL datable query to insert multiple column values

Tags: sql, oracle10g

How to add multiple values in a single column of table in SQL? My table looks like this:

```
Create table emp
(
     id number(5),
     name varchar(25),
     phone varchar(25)
);
```

Now I want to add values and multiple phones in the phone column. How to do that? I tried using

```
insert into emp values (id, name, phone) 
values (1, lee, (23455, 67543));
```

but this is not working

Comment: This is not how SQL works.  You can only have one entry for every column. Please take a basic tutorial first.

Comment: poorly designed schema then. seperate out phone number from emp table.

Comment: Either have two phone no columns (work, cell), or another table just for phone numbers.

Comment: Read up on database normalization

Comment: **Don't do this!** This violates even the **first normal form** of database design! If you need multiple values - put them in a separate table and reference the `emp` table from those new rows inserted

Comment: If you are using Postgres and you really, really think you need to do this and ignore all the warnings, then at least use an array or a `hstore` column. Not ideal, but at least a bit better than a comma separated string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `insert` statements instead

```
insert into emp values (id, name,phone) values (1,'lee','23455'); 
insert into emp values (id, name,phone) values (1,'lee','67543');
```

or If you want to store both the values in single row

```
insert into emp values (id, name,phone) values (1,'lee','23455,67543');
```

Here table is not `normalised`. You either need to store Phone Number info in separate table or use two different column in same table.

Try changing you table design like this.

**EMP table**

```
CREATE TABLE emp
  (
     emp_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
     name   VARCHAR(25)
  );
```

**PhoneNumber Table**

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumber
  (
     phoneno_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     emp_id     INT,
     Phone_Number int,
     Cell_Number Int,
     FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES emp(emp_id)
  )
```

**Note :** `Auto increment` syntax may differ based on the database you are using.

Comment: You forgot to mention that with a proper primary key you can't store two rows for a user.

Comment: meaning i need to normalise the table first ?? how do i do that ?? help me out

Comment: Please - don't advocate using **comma-separated** values in a single column! This is a mess - and it will come back and haunt you - rather sooner than later..... if you need multiple values - put them into rows in a separate, linked table - that's the relational way to do it !!

Comment: @marc_s - I have clearly mentioned OP. it is not right way to store

Comment: @Lee, in your specific case, you either have two phone number columns in you table (or 3 columns - home, work, cell), or a separate table for phone numbers. Don't forget primary keys, foreign keys, not null constraints etc.!

Comment: @Lee - Updated check now

Answer (score 1):

The **proper** and only real well-designed way to do this in a relational setting is to use a **separate** table for your phones (*this is in SQL Server specific syntax - it might be slightly different, depending on which concrete database system you're using*):

```
Create table emp
(
     id INT PRIMARY KEY,
     name varchar(25)
)

create table phone
(
     phoneId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     empid INT NOT NULL,
     phone varchar(25) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT FK_Phone_Emp
       FOREIGN KEY(empid) REFERENCES dbo.emp(id)
);
```

and then you insert the employee data into `emp` :

```
insert into emp(id, name) 
values (1, lee);
```

and the phones into `phone`:

```
insert into phone(empid, phone) values(1, 23455);
insert into phone(empid, phone) values(1, 67543);
```

With this setup, you have proper normalization for the database, and you can store *as many* phones as you like, for each employee.

Comment: Don't forget primary key for the emp table, and not null for the name and phoneno columns. And the phoneid declaration is not ANSI SQL compliant. (No dbms specified.) Add unique constraint on (empid, phone).

Comment: @jarlh: sorry, yes, I'm using SQL Server syntax here (because that's what I use every day and know well).

Comment: tell me what is IDENTITY(1,1) is used cos im getting error saying Primary Key Clustered :( error: right parenthesis missing

Comment: SQL> create table phone
  2  (
  3       phoneId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  4       empid INT NOT NULL,
  5       phone varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  6       CONSTRAINT FK_Phone_Emp
  7         FOREIGN KEY(empid) REFERENCES dbo.emp(id)
  8  );
     phoneId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                 *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @Lee: it would be **helpful** to know what **concrete database system** you're using! This syntax is for **Microsoft SQL Server** - adapt as needed